# What happens to my body when I am "inside" a Pensieve?

Tags: harry-potter, pensieve

When I am viewing memories in my Pensieve, what happens to my physical body? From the perspective of an outside observer, do I physically enter the Pensieve or am I merely standing next to it in some sort of trance?